# What is WHSSETIT?

Tags: statistics, terminology

I am working through a 7 step statistical procedure for hypothesis testing. Step 7 has a field marked `WHSSETIT?`. What does this acronym stand for and what is the expected response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google doesn't provide a definition but several use cases, all of which seem to be compatible with the interpretation "With high statistical significance experimental/empirical tests imply that".

Comment: After looking at some lectures I believe it is: "We have sufficient statistical evidence to infer that____". +1 and accept for "inferring" a very close answer quickly.

Comment: @dinkelk: We had sufficient search engines to infer that ;-)